# Convert decimal to binary and let binary length always eight using C++

Tags: c++

I need a way to convert a decimal number into a binary number in c++, but the problem is, that the length of the binary number always has to be 8bit. Is there a way to do this?

I already did a conversion like this, but the length is not always 8bits:

```
int DecimalToBinary(int decimal)
{
    int binary = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while (decimal != 0) {
        int res = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
        binary += res * count;
        count *= 10;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

**Here is a little example of what I want to get as output:**

**This is what I get:**

255 > 11111111

5 -> 101

**This is what I want:**

255 -> 11111111

5 -> 00000101

Comment: "Decimal" and "binary" are properties of character strings, not numbers. You are converting the number to another number whose decimal string contains digits 0 and 1. Then however you're printing it, not shown, doesn't add any extra `0` characters in front.

Comment: @interjay I was actually at the same thought, but that would output `10100000` if the same logic is kept.

Comment: I say short-circuit all the manual work and learn the fmt library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're not converting decimal to binary, you're converting to another decimal number of which the output mimics a binary number. (for value five you're really outputting value one-hundered-and-one)

But you can use std::bitset to get the output you want :

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // sets of 8 bits
    std::bitset<8> twofivefive{ 255 };
    std::bitset<8> five{ 5 };

    // output : 11111111
    std::cout << twofivefive.to_string() << "\n";

    // output : 00000101
    std::cout << five.to_string() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: @sweenish oh, I was on the totally wrong track, sorry.